# How to run ARKit on iPhone 6 ?

Tags: ios, arkit

I know it doesn't support it but I just want to use the background image view for my game testing. Is there any way to use ARKit for iPhone 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run an app with ARKit on an iPhone 6. It won't crash, but the view will be blank.

Comment: Anyway to simply access the camera background ?

Comment: You should use AVFoundation to create a camera view instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple, in order to use ARKit, iOS devices need to have an A9, A10 or A11 chip, and the device which support ARkit is iPhone 6s and later.

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation: don't, you can't, it's not supported, you shouldn't hack it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different AR libraries on iPhone6 such as VoidAR or VuforiaSDK.

Answer (score -1):

IPhone 6 specs are A8 and ARkit supports A9 or greater. Don't waste valuable time with outdated equipment. If you are an amateur dev like myself its best just to not force it. ARkit will run on Iphone 6 but you cannot do for example Unity3d supported content with it. You have to build pure Swift + ARKit. Good luck.